# Why the codes for the Carousel is not working?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, angular-routing

I am trying to design a carousel using bootstrap and angular js. The portion of the code responsible for my carousel is given below.

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
          
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                <img src="../assets/img3.jpg" alt="Monster Book of Monsters" class="image">
              </div>
          
              <div class="item">
                <img src="../assets/img4.jpg" alt="Awesome Deals" class="image">
              </div>
          
              <div class="item">
                <img src="../assets/img3.jpg" alt="Monster Book of Monsters" class="image">
              </div>
            </div>
          
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
          </div>
```

My issue is that due to the href included in the anchor tag, everytime I try to change the image by clicking on the icons,the #mycarousel gets appended to my url. The code for my routes are given below.

```
const routes: Routes = [
/* Include the neccessary paths for routing */

{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch:'full' },
{ path: 'collection', component: CollectionComponent,pathMatch:'full' },

{path:'about',component:AboutComponent,pathMatch:"full"},

{path:'signing',component:SigningComponent,pathMatch:"full"},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/about', pathMatch:'full' }];
```

Due to "path: '**', redirectTo: '/about', pathMatch:'full' " this line in my route path definitions , everytime #mycarousel gets appended to my url , I get diverted to /about page.

I have also tried to remove the href anchor tag but my carousel is not working.
What should I do?

Comment: The carousel component of bootstrap requires its JavaScript to work. In order to implement this, you will have to write your own code (use a directive maybe) because as at this date, although angular successfully imports bootstrap CSS, it does not successfully import the scripts required to work with bootstrap (that is bootstrap.min.js, popper.min.js etc).

You could also use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples) and [here is a tutorial](https://yogeshdotnet.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-carousel-in-angular-5-6/) on it

Comment: @sudo_kaizen.......Going by the demo that you have provided...the images are getting stacked up one below the other.

Comment: Then the error must be from your end because the demo is working well

Comment: got my own codes to work by adding the required js files..thanks.